# VAT Exemption Checkout Step/ Ebizmarts Sage Pay extension

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, tax, payment-methods, sagepay

I have installed the following plugins:

VAT Exempt - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vat-exempt-by-indies.html

Sage Pay - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-sage-pay-suite-ce-europe-free-sagepay-official-extension.html

What happens is that that the VAT Exempt extension adds an additional step in the one page checkout after the Payment Method step but before the Order Review step, if the user selects YES they are VAT Exempt then the Tax is removed.

Every things works great if I checkout with Check/Money Order as my payment method, the order goes through without tax and with Tax if the user selects that they are no VAT Exempt.

The issue is when SagePay is selected as the payment method. The Order Review page shows no tax (which is fine) if the user selects that they are VAT Exempt, however, when the Sage Pay FORM opens the tax is included in the value, the whole order from that point on contains the tax (Order Confirmation email and in the admin).

what I think is that the value passed to Sage Pay is set on the Payment Method Step, the user then carries on and accepts that they are VAT Exempt the tax is removed but as the value being sent to Sage Pay is already set before they select VAT Exempt status the tax is being included.

Is there any way around this? Any fix? Ideas? or Suggestions. I'm pretty stumped and we got the website scheduled to go live early next week :/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: contact the developer of this extension.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about two third party extensions. Please contact the developers directly for support.

Comment: The interplay between two extensions is out of scope for this forum. You can contact ebizmarts about this issue though as they are a very response company and might be able to add a VAT exemption step to their extension.